# Empty search field

Tags: search, user-research

What is recommended to handle the scenario "User entered empty/null" value in the search bar. Its in eBook.

Just want to know the genius way to handle apart from providing the error message like "Enter some search text"

Comment: Clarifying if I understand your question correctly: are you asking what is the recommended user experience when the user doesn't type any text inside a search textbox and presses enter (or the search button)?

Comment: yes @staccato.. Exactly. When a user enters null value in the search bar and presses enter, what could be the best approach to handle the situation in terms of user experience.

Comment: The error message should say: *"You can't have everything. Where would you put it?"*

Comment: haha.. +1 for this. sounds humour though.

Answer (score 1):

**There could be two possible solutions.**

1. Keep the button disabled and let the user know when he try to hit
   the button using alert/popover/error message
2. Keep the button active but do nothing if a user hit submit but
   show error message.

Check being a user what would you expect in that scenario?

Comment: For the record, I would *highly* recommend the second approach, as, the first relies on the user taking some action (even if it is just a hover) on a button that is visibly disabled.  If they don't take that action, they will never know why the button is disabled.

Answer (score 1):

Use a **Snackbar** (Toast) to show a message.

Snackbars (toasts) are often used as tooltips/popups to show a message at the bottom of the screen, that fade out within seconds.

[Learn how to create a snackbar / toast with CSS and JavaScript.](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_snackbar.asp)